# Transferable force

Tags: forces, statics

If I for example have two rectangular pieces of steel that are both W=40mm, L=1000mm, H= 40mm and are both completely ridged. One piece of steel is resting on top of the other piece of steel, if I then apply force of 5kg at points A, B, and C vertically downward on the top piece of steel, will the force being exerted on the second piece of steel at points A, B, and C be exactly the same? A total resultant force of 15kg evenly distributed being applied onto the second piece of steel. Please see attached picture.[image: Diagram of question]

Answer (score 0):

First off -The Kilogram is not a unit of force.You might want to correct that to 5 Newtons,or 5 kgf.
Setting that aside and taking 5 Newtons as the given force,from the picture you have given if we neglect the mass of the overlying steel slab which in this case is unknown(but calculable), then in an ideal condition a net force : F=5+5+5 Newtons is being applied at both the bodies with an equitable distribution at all points.And yes, since they are fixed  a torque acting at any point A,B,C cannot turn the body in any direction.

See more at: http://www.mathalino.com/reviewer/engineering-mechanics/resultant-of-parallel-force-system#sthash.7PIK7zy2.dpuf
Hope this helps!